# Using ViewTreeObserver's addOnGlobalLayoutListener to get XY position, returns 0 for view.getX() on Rotation

Tags: android, android-layout

Below code snippet shows how i am trying access view X and Y cords but it returns `Y` value accurate but `X` returns `0` always.

**Code Snippet :**

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(blockView.getParent());
vg.setRotation(-45f);
vg.setRotationX(55f);
ViewTreeObserver vto2 = blockView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto2.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
       @Override
       public void onGlobalLayout()   {                                       
        System.out.println("Block VIEW X > " + blockView.getX()); //returns 0
        System.out.println("Block VIEW Y > " + blockView.getY()); //returns value.

       }
 });
```

So can any one tell me what change i should do or suggest some other approach to do the same.

Comment: Whether that view is on left side?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want a to add a view dynamically at particular X Y position in that viewGroup

Comment: I'd say that if the getY() is returning the correct value, so is getX(). There might be some issues with your layout, but you'll need to post additional info (the layout and a screenshot would be really helpfull).